# Under the hood of Uninformative Prior?

Tags: statistics, pymc

What distribution is being used under the hood of PyMC's Uninformative prior? Is there a way to provide constraints, e.g. value>=0, along with the initial value to force the "walk" in a certain direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing under the hood of the Uninformative prior (literally) -- it returns a log-likelihood of zero irrespective of the arguments passed to it. If you want to constrain it, the easiest approach is to use a factor potential to inject a log-likelihood term with the particular constraints you want (I'm assuming you are dealing with PyMC 2.3 here, but the same goes with PyMC 3).

```
x = Uninformative('x', value=1)

@potential
def x_pos(x=x):
    if x<=0:
        return -inf
    return 0
```

Comment: When I want to use `MAP.fit`, I find it helps to use a "soft constraint", i.e. return `-1e6 * x**2` instead of `-inf` when the constraint is violated.  This helps the hill-climber find its way.